# cocoa: how to create new SBElementArray?

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I'm making a application which read emails in Mail.app. Firstly, the application get all senders from Mail.app using

```
    NSArray *emailSenders = [self.mailBox.messages arrayByApplyingSelector:@selector(sender)];
```

I have to display target user email content, e.g. only show all mails from "abc@gmail.com", so I get the sender indexes which contain the target user email

```
[emailSenders enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *emailSender, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if([emailSender rangeOfString:userEmail].location != NSNotFound){
        [emails addObject:[self.mailBox.messages objectAtIndex:idx]];
    }
}];
```

emails is a SBElementArray created by

```
    SBElementArray *emails = [[SBElementArray alloc]init];
```

I want to fetch all contents in emails by sending Apple Script Event only once, like

```
[mails arrayByApplyingSelector:@selector(content)];
```

so I create my own SBElementArray, but the problem is Xcode display:`*** -[SBElementArray init]: should never be used.`
 when I run this code, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your filtered items to an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, and remember that its elements are `SBObjects`.

Comment: but I need to fetch filtered items content by sending apple script agagin, like `[mails arrayByApplyingSelector:@selector(content)];`

Comment: @remysystem does that not work for some reason in practice? i figured it would be the same because the evaluation materialized in the process of evaluating `sender`. however, it's been a while since i worked with ScriptingBridge; i could be wrong.